# How can you load data dynamically with the FMPP Java API?

Tags: java, freemarker, fmpp

I am integrating a FMPP transformation into our Java code base. For this, I am using the [FMPP Java API](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/api/index.html). For practical reasons, I have two separate directories:

- one which contains the template: `<absolute path template>/template.ftlx`
- one which contains the data: `<absolute path data>/data.xml`

This somehow complicates things, as I have to work with absolute paths here. Typically, the data is inside the template directory (together with a `ignoredir.fmpp` file). However, in our application, the data is coming from an external source (it is uploadable via a REST API), while the template is in the classpath. This also means that the data directory isn't static.

I am struggling to define all this and get the transformation happening via the Java API. Currently, I have the following:

```
Settings s = new Settings(new File("."));

s.set(Settings.NAME_SOURCES, new File("<absolute path template>/template.ftlx").getAbsolutePath());
s.set(Settings.NAME_OUTPUT_FILE, new File("<absolute path output>/output.xml").getAbsolutePath());
s.execute();
```

The code snippet above is not complete, as I have to add the data. There are the `Settings.NAME_DATA` and `Settings.NAME_DATA_ROOT` properties, but I can't get it working. I tried setting `Settings.NAME_DATA_ROOT` as following:

```
s.set(Settings.NAME_DATA_ROOT, new File("<absolute path data>").getAbsolutePath());
```

Then, I get the exception that FreeMarker cannot find my data:

```
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> d  [in template "template.ftlx" at line 4, column 12]
```

In the template, I simply do:

```
<#list d.items>...</#list>
```

This makes sense that this would not work, as I did nowhere define that the data should be accessible via the `d.` hash (which I am doing below in `config.fmpp`). But I don't know how to define that properly via `Settings.NAME_DATA` and/or `Settings.NAME_DATA_ROOT`.

How can I inject my data file into all this? It should get the key `d`, so I can refer to `d.` in the template.

**reference**

Just as reference, if I create the following `config.fmpp` file in `<absolute path config>`, put the `data.xml` data file in directory `<absolute path data>` and call `s.load(new File("<absolute path config>/config.fmpp"))` before `s.execute()` above, everything is working fine.

```
data: {
    d: xml(<absolute path data>/data.xml)
}
```

All I have to figure out is doing this in a dynamic fashion via the Java API. I cannot use `config.fmpp` for this, as the location of the data isn't static (and, as far as I know, `config.fmpp` is not parametrizable).

**working solution, with doubts**

After some code reading, I got it working if I do the following:

```
Settings s = new Settings(new File("."));

s.set(Settings.NAME_SOURCES, new File("<absolute path template>/template.ftlx").getAbsolutePath());
s.set(Settings.NAME_OUTPUT_FILE, new File("<absolute path output>/output.xml").getAbsolutePath());
s.set(Settings.NAME_DATA, "{d:xml(<absolute path output>/data.xml)}");

s.execute();
```

Here, we pass `{configuration:xml(<absolute path output>/data.xml)}` as a TDD to the `NAME_DATA` property. Is this the way to go? It "feels" strange to construct a textual definition in our code. Is there a way to do this in pure Java?

Comment: Similarly as you set `sources` with `Settings.set`, you should be able to set `dataRoot`. You say that it doesn't work, but I think it should, so maybe look into more, why it doesn't work.

Comment: I added additional information regarding setting `dataRoot`. Am I doing that right? Is there an example somewhere? I tried looking into `src/docs/examples` on github, but I can't find Java API examples.

Comment: @ddekany I got something working, see update at the bottom of the question. It works, but I'm not sure I'm doing it properly. Could you please take a look? Thank you, highly appreciated.

Comment: I think that if you have the `Engine` object, then `engine.addData("d", new XmlDataLoader(engine, args))` will do that. Yeah, it still has `List<?> args`... seems I did not consider calling that API from application code. Still better than calling `Settings` API, which is clearly about config files. And by the way, `Engine` has methods for the other settings you use too.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll use `Engine` directly.